# How To Give Two icons in a same div in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to display to icons with out having text like `left arrow and right arrow`

and the output is like the following:

```
<  Saturday Sep 08 2012 >
```

I have tried like the following:

```
<div data-role=content data-theme="c" style="text-align:center"  >
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext"></a> 
        <span><font size="1px" color="blue" >Saturday Sep 08 2012</font></span>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext"></a> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their own [Grid system](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/content/content-grids.html).

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
  <div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">Block B</div>
  <div class="ui-block-c">Block C</div>
</div>
```

in your example, you would have something like this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"> 
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <span><font size="1px" color="blue" >Saturday Sep 08 2012</font></span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

from your comments, all you need to do is use your own styling to align the elements in the correct place.

See this **live example**: http://jsbin.com/imokaw/1/edit

Comment: That's not jQueryMobile, that's only CSS then, you can add your own classes that display anything you like. Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/imokaw/1/